# nodemon, babel-node: how to set environment variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, nodemon

Dev environment starts with this command:

```
nodemon -w src --exec \"babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0\"
```

How do i create a global variable (or `process.env` variable) `__DEV__ = true`?

Comment: If you're running in bash, it's just `__DEV__="true" nodemon -w src --exec \"babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0\"`. It'll probably come in as a string, you'll have to parse it or rely on it's absence for truthiness/falsiness.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this just without quotes, as suggested in all discussions i've seen and it didn't work.

Comment: where do you want create this variable?

Answer (score 11):

You can either add `"env"` property to `nodemon.json`, like this:

```
...
"env": {
    "__DEV__": "true"
}
```

Or you can prepend `__DEV__="true"` to `start` script in `package.json`.
Both worked for me.

Comment: This is not a good approach because the environment variables will be pushed in the repository. The best way is using `env` files and ignoring in the `gitignore` file.

Answer (score 11):

You can add a "nodemonConfig" property to package.json with your env info. Then execute nodemon in your scripts section.

```
"nodemonConfig": {
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
  "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "delay": "2500",
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development",
    "NODE_CONFIG_DIR": "./config"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good approach because the environment variables will be pushed in the repository. The best way is using `env` files and ignoring in the `gitignore` file.

Comment: @valdeci No. That's only if you want to override env for local configuration. There are plenty of reasons to want to set an environment variable that is the same for everyone that uses it. Using `.env` is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

For windows: `set __DEV__ = true&&nodemon -w src --exec \"babel-node src --presets es2015,stage-0\`"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to handle the env variables in the nodemon call, you can do something like this.

1. Create a file called '.env' and put something like this in it:

   **DEV**=true
2. Then in your application entry file put the following line in as early as possible:

   ```
   require('dotenv').config();
   ```

Comment: If you are going to take this approach, there are better ways to include the values and keep them in scope instead of setting them to environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) module on my projects.

We just need to create a `.env` file and require the `dotenv` module in our project:

**`.env` file**:

```
 __DEV__="true"
```

**`your-script.js` file**:

```
require('dotenv').config();

console.log(process.env.__DEV__)
```

Creating `.env` files is normally a good option since we can prevent to commit our environment files using `.gitignore`

Answer (score -3):

just define in codes (server file) like this `proccess.env.VARIABLE="true"`

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin why defeats?

Comment: Because the purpose of an environment variable is to allow your process to be controlled by whichever agent is starting it, i.e. its environment. If you hardcode the value in the code, there is no point to even using environment variables, since the process environment can no longer have any control over the process.

Comment: no you can use this variable every where in project @AsadSaeeduddin

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I'm saying. If I define the value of the environment variable in my code, then someone else who takes my code and tries to start it cannot pass any values for said environment variables. They're no longer variables, but rather constants.

Comment: ok i get it, your right, but in this case of using you have not to define variable every time you start the script,specially if you have one agent for project

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, you are right in general, environment variable has to be set by some external agent, but the thing is that the nodemon is the external agent that starts you application, it especially helpful when you are running application for development purposes on you local machine, it helps you to rely on the same environment variables always. The difference it only could be in the ways how you set them on production and on your local machine.

Comment: A set of preset scripts can be a good idea if you know what you're doing.  Some people are way too quick to dismiss an idea.